# Hibernate Order by Descending and then ascending

Tags: hibernate

How can I order by descending and take max results and at end I want list to sort ascending. I have the following code which is not working

```
Criteria cr = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("empId", empId)).add(Restrictions.eq("empCode", empCode));
    cr.addOrder(Order.desc("joinDate"));
    cr.setMaxResults(5);
    cr.addOrder(Order.asc("joinDate"));
    return cr.list();
```

Comment: It's easier to reorder later in Java. Just use a simple Comparator

Comment: Can you give me some more guide about it as I have never used Comparator before.

Comment: Essentially you're doing `ORDER BY joinDate DESC LIMIT 5` after which you want to change the order. That requires you either use a subquery or you just sort them in Java as @StanislavL suggested, which would be easier in this case.

Comment: If I have to get minimum empId from above code and store it in a string than what is the best way to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

noOfEmployee is the list return from the above criteria which you should initialize and Employee is the model class.

```
    Collections.sort(noOfEmployee, new Comparator<Employee>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1.getJoinDate().compareTo(o2.getJoinDate());
        }
    });
```

Comment: o1.getJoinDate().compareTo(o2.getJoinDate()) could throw NPE

Comment: You should save the comparator in a `final static` field, so you don't allocate/deallocate memory for it every time.

Comment: well i am getting query from dao and i am doing this sorting on my service layer

Comment: StanislavL can you just illustrate me how it will throw NPE as I haven't witnessed anything from the code

Answer (score 0):

this is for when you are use List

```
List<Incident> sortedIncidents = employee.getIncidents().stream()                       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Incident::getCreatedOn).reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this is for when you are use Set

```
    Set<Incident> sortedIncidents = new TreeSet<>(
                    (incident1, incident2) -> incident2.getCreatedOn().compareTo(incident1.getCreatedOn()));
```